# jQuery select input fields with the same placeholder value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select all input fields with the same placeholder-value. In this case "value1"

I can't edit the HTML due to the condition that I have to hack a PlugIn.

Here's my HTML:

```js
$('input[placeholder="value1"]').on('keyup', function() {
  $('.' + $(this).attr('placeholder')).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Row 1:
<input type="text" placeholder="value1">
<input type="text" placeholder="value1">
<br> Row 2:
<input type="text" placeholder="value2">
<input type="text" placeholder="value3">
```

How do I select the placeholder-value?

Comment: You need to use alternate quotes. `$('input[placeholder="value1"]')`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thx for the quick reply. Sadly it still doesn't work. I edited the question tho.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code itself doesn't make sense

Comment: @AlonEitan I'm trying to mirror the input for all input fields with "value1" as placeholder.

Comment: Firstly, there is no `.value1` element in the HTML. Secondly, if you already know the `placeholder` then you know the class, so the point of selecting by the placeholder is entirely redundant. Lastly, if there are multiple classes matching the placeholder, then you'll need a method of differentiating them, but you've not shown that in the HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The PlugIn I'm talking about doesn't generate classes for the input fields and the only thing I can edit is the placeholder value.

Comment: I'm not saying you need to put classes on the inputs. I'm saying the element that you're trying to target in this example, `.value1`, `.value2`, etc. does not exist. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what `$('.' + $(this).attr('placeholder'))` is doing is: Select all elements with the same *class* like the value of the `placeholder` attribute of the currently edited element.

Perhaps you're looking for `$('[placeholder="' + $(this).attr('placeholder') + '"]')`?
(Hopefully I got the quotation marks right)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ if you need a refresher on the selectors in jQuery.

Comment: What are you expecting `$(this)` in `$('[placeholder="' + $(this).attr('placeholder') + '"]')` to be?

Comment: That would be the `<input>` element currently typed into. Resp. the jQuery wrapper around it.

Comment: I mean, that would work, but selecting an element in an event handler running on the element you already selected seems redundant. You could just use `this`. It's not at all clear what the OP is trying to do here, though.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you want to read the placeholder of the current selected item and use that.

```js
$('input[placeholder="value1"]').on('keyup', function() {
  $('input[placeholder=' + $(this).attr('placeholder') + ']').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Row 1:
<input type="text" placeholder="value1">
<input type="text" placeholder="value1">
<br> Row 2:
<input type="text" placeholder="value2">
<input type="text" placeholder="value3">
```